# What is a cost effective app to resize, crop & save a MOV file to a reduced size?

Tags: video, compression

I am planning to buy an HD animation which is over 500Meg in size.

I need to resize, crop and reduce the file size to about 10Meg.

I prefer not to deal with Adobe Media Encoder or something like ffmpeg.

Is there something out there from under $20 that will do the job?

Answer (score 0):

Import the animation in an NLE (such as DaVinci Resolve, which is free and powerful) and export the cropped animation from it by running compression and export tests until you get a file that has the size and quality you're looking for. No need to use MediaEncoder or FFMPEG.